# SQL data sorting dynamically

Tags: sql-server

Let us consider message chat
Case
User wanted to get last 100 msg 
When he scroll up again he have to get 100 more like that we have to get data how to write query in SQL Server

Explanation
Let us consider 4 people are there in a group and chatting
Every one last 50 records at least
He can go back again i.e he have to get last 51-100
Then again scrolling means
1001-151

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What is your data structure? Give an example? What do you get til now, your sql tries?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for simple pagination query:

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT
       ,@PageNumber INT

SET @PageSize = 50
SET @PageNumber = 1

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MessagesTable
ORDER BY MessageDateAdded DESC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

You are simply querying the `50` most recent messages:

```
SET @PageSize = 50
```

and

```
ORDER BY MessageDateAdded DESC
```

You can make a SQL routine that accept as parameter `@PageNumber`. You also need to get in the application the current user `page number`. So, when the user needs to load the previous page, you are just passing to the function `current page number + 1`.

Also, to use [`OFFSET-FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you need SQL Server 2012+. Otherwise, you need to implement the pagination yourself. Let me know if you do not how.

Answer (score 0):

You can make SQL query like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [YOUR_CONDITION]
```

This will give you top 100 rows from your table.